# How to create an extended xfail marker for py.test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

In `py.test` (version 4.6.2) you have a mark-decorator for a test to mark it as failed, e.g.

```
@pytest.mark.xfail
def test1():
    return 1/0
```

It is also possible to verify the exception itself

```
@pytest.mark.xfail(raises=ZeroDivisionError)
```

but is it possible in some way to verify the error message itself?

this is useful when you have a `HTTPError`, as there can be many reasons. And when you compare the error message itself you can be much more specific about when the test fails (e.g. distinguish a certain `Client Error` from a `Server Error`).

I am using the following construct so far:

```
def test_fail_request(self):      
    with pytest.raises(requests.exceptions.HTTPError) as excinfo:
        response = requests.something
    assert '403 Client Error: Not Found' in str(excinfo.value)
```

but of course a test like the follows would be more readable, compact and correctly handled by `py.test`:

```
 @pytest.mark.xfail(expected_error = "403 Client Error: Not Found"):
 def test_fail_request(self):      
    response = requests.something
```

Is there a way to implement this behavior/feature?

To clarify, the last code example is expected to fail, but only when the error message contains a certain message (example: `400 Client Error: Bad Request`). In that case, the test will be reported as `XFAIL`.

But if the test fails and creates a *different* error message (even for the same exception, but e.g. `500 Server Error` in the error message instead), the test must be reported as “unexpectedly passing” (`XPASS`).

Comment: If that request supposed to fail or not? `pytest.mark.xfail` is used in cases when something is failing that should not, e.g. pending a bug fix. Whereas `assert` is marking something as expected behavior. Which one do you need?

Comment: Yes, the request in the example code is expected to fail. But only with a very specific error message. Not just every `HTTPError`. Only a `HTTPError` with a specific error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the failure is normal behavior, you could create your own decorator, e.g.:

```py
import functools
def expect_http_error(func=None, *, expected_error):
  def wrapper(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
      with pytest.raises(requests.exceptions.HTTPError) as excinfo:
        func(*args, **kwargs)
      assert expected_error in str(excinfo.value)

    return inner

  return wrapper if func is None else wrapper(func)
```

And then you use it like so:

```py
@expect_http_error(expected_error = "403 Client Error: Not Found")
def test_fail_request(self):      
  response = requests.something
```

Comment: That solution is useable and easy to adapt to return the correct error state (like `XFAIL` and `FAIL`. There is no `XPASS` method you can use, but whatever).